# Replacing illegal or undesired characters in requested URL before processing it .net

Tags: c#, .net, iis

My site throws an exception every time a special kind of character is included in the request, or when the size of the URL exceeds a certain length.

How can I control the URL and transform it before processing it (For example : if the request was http://xwz.com/"ert I want to turn it into http://xwz.com/ert). Something like that.

I am using .net and c#

Comment: http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/ may help

Comment: I think in this circumstance I'd not try to "clean up" the URLs. Why are you trying to reward bad behaviour?

Comment: Because it is not human behavior I am trying to take care of, I am after the bots especially bots that help determine the credibility of my site, instead of reporting an internal error I can at least take them to a 404 page not found.

Answer (score 2):

use this : [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28VS.80%29.aspx)

You can use it like this :

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("test t");
```

You will need this library : `UrlEncode uses`**`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`**`to encode strings.`

Comment: I'm still confused on how to use this method.
Let's say the request came in as www.xyz.com/"abc I want to turn it into www.xyz.com/abc

1 - where shall I place the code? 
2 - How to use urlencode method in this example?

Comment: Are you saying the user typed this in or that you have it programmatically?  If former, you are talking about browser-level application handling. If the latter, at any time before you process the request url, you can encode and enforce length.

Comment: I am saying I am receiving a request that includes a character that causes the site to throw an exception. And this character is ", which it keeps getting translated into %22 and the application looks at it as if it is part of the physical path...So all I am trying to do is to atleast get rid of this character and replace it with nothing or any other character that can at least produce a page not found instead of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

> The UrlEncode(String) method can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values. If characters such as blanks and punctuation are passed in an HTTP stream without encoding, they might be misinterpreted at the receiving end. URL encoding converts characters that are not allowed in a URL into character-entity equivalents; URL decoding reverses the encoding. For example, when the characters < and > are embedded in a block of text to be transmitted in a URL, they are encoded as %3c and %3e.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will replace any invalid characters in your URL by an empty space

```
           string url = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(url , @"/^[!#$&-;=?-[]_a-z~]+$/", "");
```

Comment: Where exactly shall I place this code? The string url needs to be replaced with the request url I assume?

Comment: @Amjad In the example i have given, url is the string that you want to check for illegal characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:
    System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)